# What is the most standard criteria for 'partial match' in sql select queries?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have been asked that the queries to the database be partial match.

Generally, to use partial match with `LIKE` we need to know which wildcard we are going to use for pattern matching, right?.

My question is: is there a 'generic' case to apply partial match without having any specific constraints?

This is an example query that I use in my project, could someone give me an example of how to do this query 'partial match' without any specific constraints?

```
select
    a.*,
    coalesce(nullif(a.aachange, '.'), nullif(a.detailref, '.') ) as var,
    b.*,
    c.*
from
    db-dummy.data c
join db-dummy.info a on
    a.record_id = c.var_id
join db-dummy.s_data b on
    b.record_id = c.s_id
order by
    a.g_name;
```

**UPDATE:**

I am going to add more information about the desired output.

Let's say I have a column:

```
+------------+
|    Col     |
+------------+
| ABCDEFG    |
| ABCDEFGH   |
| ABCDEFGHI  |
| AB12398JKH |
+------------+
```

If `Where Col = 'AB'`, the result should be: `ABCDEFG, ABCDEFGH, ABCDEFGHI, AB12398JKH`

If `Where Col = 'ABC'` the result should be: `ABCDEFG, ABCDEFGH, ABCDEFGHI`

If `Where Col = 'ABCDEFGH'` the result should be: `ABCDEFGH, ABCDEFGHI`

If `Where Col = 'ABCDEFGHI'` the result should be: `ABCDEFGHI`

Comment: Please provide sample and desired results.  Explain what "partial match" means in this context.

Comment: The desired output is: if a substring is included in a result(s) show them all instead of showing only the exact match result. I think that's more or less what they expect me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `LIKE`:

```
where col like concat('AB', '%')
```

You can pass in the `'AB'` as a parameter.  Or set the parameter up with the wildcard (`'AB%'`).

Comment: Yes but, what if I don't know what the user will input for searching? 

In the provided example we know it's going to be AB...blabla so we can use 'AB', what if we have infinite options? That's why I need a generic answer, but it is not clear to me how to do that.

Comment: @Cheknov . . . As the answer points out, you can pass the search string as a parameter.

Comment: Another option is to use the [REGEXP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp/) operator to provide a more complex syntax.